# Update parent dict in subclass

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, metaclass

I have classes like this:

```
class Parent(object):
    _defaults = {
        'key': 'value',
        'key2': 'value',
    }

class Child(Parent):
    _defaults = {
        'key2': 'value2',
        'key3': 'value2',
    }
```

When I create the child class, I want `_defaults` to be set to the parent class `_defaults` and then updated with the child `_defaults`. So the actual resolved class should look like this:

```
class Child(object):
    _defaults = {
        'key': 'value',
        'key2': 'value2',
        'key3': 'value2',
    }
```

Is this possible with a `__metaclass__` constructor or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a metaclass you need to do this in `__new__` method, in order to apply the changes before instantiation. Since the `__new__` method accepts `cls, name, bases, namespace, **kwds` as argument you can simply access to parent object using `bases` argument which is a tuple of all base classes then you can simply update your expected attribute.

```
class MyMetaClass(type):

    def __new__(cls, name, bases, namespace, **kwds):
        bases[0]._defaults.update(namespace['_defaults'])
        result = type.__new__(cls, name, bases, dict(namespace))
        return result


class Parent(object):
    _defaults = {
        'key': 'value',
        'key2': 'value',
    }

class Child(Parent, metaclass=MyMetaClass):
    _defaults = {
        'key2': 'value2',
        'key3': 'value2',
    }
```

Demo:

```
c = Child()    
print(type(c).__bases__[0]._defaults)
{'key2': 'value2', 'key3': 'value2', 'key': 'value'}
```

Note that as @jsbueno mentioned this method has a big problem which is updating the parent class's `_defaults` attribute at each instantiation. One approach for refusing this problem might be providing the meta class with a flag in order to update the parent only once.

Comment: Ideally you would use `ChainMap`, as given in another answer, but this works well enough.

Comment: @xaav Yes, that's a good approach. But I posted this answer as I though that OP is looking for a metaclass based solution for an educational purpose.

Comment: I'm the one who posted the question!

Comment: the answer in .en is fine, but your code has a series of problems (of course, mostly due to you only intending to write a simple example): the most grave being that it actually updates the defaults on the parent class for each instantiated child class. Another thing is that it only checks `bases[0] ` not all classes in the `__mro__` - and, of course, it would be better to declare the metaclass on the `Parent` at once.

Comment: @jsbueno Yes I intended to give a simple example. Regarding the bases(0) that's right but it can be done with a simple loop. But about the updating the parent fr each instance I think that's
what the OP wants, and actually I can't imagine how should it be if it's not going to update the parent for each instance.

Comment: On update the parent on each instance, you have each subclass declaration modifying the superclass. That is _not_ what inheritance and OOP is about: the subclasses differ fromt e superclasses themselves. There is no sense in updating the parent `_defaults`. Even if the OP was decided asking for this, y9u should warn about it (but I can't read that from the question)

Comment: @jsbueno I am happy to mark a different answer as correct it better addresses the question. In fact I'm not completely satisfied with this answer, but it was the only one which joined defaults inside the metaclass, which is what I was looking for.

Comment: @jsbueno Indeed, that's a good point. And yes I should mentioned that bot unfortunately I missed it. I'll update the question. Thanks for attention.

Comment: @xaav, this is mostly good - I think it could jsut get some more love to be  a good reference for people who, sometimes , just "copy and paste" code when needed. This is not that an uncommon case, and sometimes the metaclass solution is needed isntead of the chainmap .

Answer (score 3):

You can accomplish this using a `collections.ChainMap`

```
import collections

class Child(Parent):
    _defaults = collections.ChainMap({
        'key2': 'value2',
        'key3': 'value2',
    }, Parent._defaults)
```

Of course, you *could* write a metaclass to combine these things for you, but it would be tricky to figure out (in general) which maps *should* be combined with the maps on the superclasses and which should override...

Answer (score 1):

Read the dictionary items directly, then update?

```
class Parent(object):
    _defaults = {
        'key': 'value',
        'key2': 'value',
    }


class Child(Parent):
    _defaults = {k: v for k, v in Parent._defaults.items()}
    _defaults.update({'key2': 'value2',
                      'key3': 'value2'})


testpar = Parent()
test = Child()

print(testpar._defaults)
print(test._defaults)
```

prints:

```
{'key2': 'value', 'key': 'value'}
{'key3': 'value2', 'key2': 'value2', 'key': 'value'}
```

in both 2.7 and 3.5

Comment: Why not `_defaults = Parent._defaults.copy()`?